# Suggested icons for the status of downloading content

Tags: icons, online-offline

We are designing the UI for the downloading of content for offline mode in a PWA app.

We will use the [solid](https://fontawesome.com/icons/download?style=solid) and/or [light](https://fontawesome.com/icons/download?style=light) download icons   to allow users to download the content (which which they will be able to download atomically).

[image: solid download image] [image: light download image]

How would you portray that a resource has or has not been downloaded?

How would you convey to the user that a resource is not available to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Has been downloaded: the Resource itself (icon that symbolize it, like papersheet or folder) is shown instead of Download button (see how some browsers do that). If not applicable, then the Resource is shown instead of Down Arrow. In your case, the Resource is over physical device with two LEDs.
2. Has not yet been downloaded, but is available for: your Download icon.
3. Unable to download: probably X-cross instead of Down Arrow over the Device.
4. Not available to download? You mean, not available from the beginning? Then you probably don't need to show anything in this case.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I like all those ideas. Most of the resources will be offline webpages rather than files. For point 4 yes I mean content that the user would never be able to download (if for example we have not yet created the feature to allow them to download that content type).